# How to decrypt nsstring using RNCryptor after conversion from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, nsstring, rncryptor

Is there anyway to decrypt a NSString using RNcryptor that has been converted from NSData? I keep getting the unknown header error. Here is what I am doing to encrypt:

```
    NSData *data = [@"FeedMeMorePizzaPlease" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                  withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:@"pizzaHutIsTheWorst"
                                           error:&error];
    NSString *encString = [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

I then take encString, put it in a text file on my server and then:

```
    NSURL  *gUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurlissupersecret.com/cheese.txt"];
    NSString *sillyString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:gUrl encoding:(NSUTF8StringEncoding) error:nil];
    NSData *blindData  = [sillyString dataUsingEncoding:0];
    NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:blindData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"pizzaHutIsTheWorst" error:&error];
```

Is there anyway to do this? Or do I have to always encrypt / decrypt a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a step in the decryption. `sillyString` is the base64 encoded string. You need to convert the base64 encoded string into `NSData`. Here is the updated code you need to decrypt:

```
NSURL  *gUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurlissupersecret.com/cheese.txt"];
NSString *encString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:gUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData *encryptedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encString options:0];
NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"pizzaHutIsTheWorst" error:&error];
```

Comment: I still get  the unknown header error. error is Error Domain=net.robnapier.RNCryptManager Code=2 "Unknown header"

Comment: Do some logging of the values during both the encryption and decryption steps. Compare `encString` in both and make sure they are the same in both directions. Compare `encryptedData` in both and make sure they are the same in both directions. Narrow down what's different.

Comment: When logging encString in the encryption step, it is different every time.

Comment: That's fine. Log what it is when you encrypt it and then log it when you decrypt it. They should be same.

Comment: But you get `encString` before you decrypt the data.

Comment: Yes, I I have no problem encrypting/decrypting strings and data with RNCryptor.

Comment: After following the steps in your answer do you see any reason that I would get the unknown header error?

Comment: Ok, I did get this working. Here is the difference:     NSData *encryptedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:gUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] options:0];

Comment: That's what I had in my answer but split on two lines.

Comment: I thought thats what I had as well, after pasting in your answer, but I guess something was off. Thanks.